# Using Fineuploader to upload a video and thumbnail together

Tags: fine-uploader

I'm using Fineuploader to upload a video file to s3 bucket. I am able to accomplish this.

Now, before I upload the video, I would like to grab a thumbnail of the video, and I am able to do this too.

Here's what I would like to do after I get the thumbnail:

- When I click the upload button, I would like to upload both the video and the thumbnail together in a single request. I have set `multiple=false` as I want the user to select only one video file at a time.

How can I upload both together?

Comment: What do you mean by "together"? Both files In a single request?

Comment: Yes, i would like to send both files in a single request using one upload button.

Comment: @RayNicholus let me correct myself, i am fine sending each file in a separate request, but would like to use only one Fineuploader instance and use canvas to grab thumbnails. Actually this link helped me with the Fineuploader and thumbnails https://github.com/FineUploader/video-frame-uploader but it only uploads the thumbnails and not the video

Comment: ...so just add the video to Fine Uploader via `addFiles`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: Fixed spelling and added some paragraph breaks for clarity.

Comment: @RayNicholus thanks for the tip. i actually ended up doing what you suggested. I am new to the fine uploader and still trying to figure out things. Its actually an awesome uploading tool

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to send multiple files in a single request with Fine Uploader. There is really a good reason to do this, especially when you are dealing with large files, like videos. Instead, you will need to account for the fact that each file will be sent in its own request. You should consider using the chunking feature to upload large files (like videos) as well.

A similar answer to a similar question can be seen at https://stackoverflow.com/a/19255892/486979.